# LUIS Endpoint Key

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I've created a LUIS Application but when I try to enter an endpoint key, I am unable to do so (the circled dropdown is blank). I've went through to Azure to create a key and navigated back to the settings page, but the drop down is still blank. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Cheers!

[image: LUIS App Settings Screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add a key, click your account setting (top right corner, or go to https://www.luis.ai/Home/UserSettings). Under My Settings -> Subscription Keys you can add new keys to user.

Just a note - you do not have to enter a key in order to create an application. A key lets you have unlimited traffic to the endpoint. It is unnecessary if you are just starting out. (See https://www.luis.ai/Help)